# how to remove space in echo?

Tags: shell, sed

```
s#!/bin/ksh

usrid=`sql_login.sh`

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then

   echo "sql login failed-Username/Password not available in control file"

   exit -1

fi

a=`sqlplus -s ${usrid} <<EOF

set pause    off

set heading  off

set feedback off

set serveroutput off;

select 10 from dual;

exit;

EOF`

b=`sqlplus -s ${usrid} <<EOF

set pause    off

set heading  off

set feedback off

select 11 from dual;

exit;

EOF`

echo "Out of sqlplus session";

echo $a$b;
```

hi its giving output like 10 11? i need it 1011 how can i achive this?

solution:

a1=$(echo ${a#}) ;

b1=$(echo ${b#}) ;

c1=$a1$b1;

echo $c1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be spaces included in the value of a (and probably b too)

You can get rid of the space by modify the value of the variable.
assuming you have bash, ksh or other POSIX shell

```
echo ${a% }${b% }
```

will probably work.
${var% } says, for ${var} remove from the right of the variable's value a space char (if there is one there.
If for some reason,  you find that the space is in the front, like ' a', then use
${a# }, which means remove from the left of the variable's value a space char.

EDIT : kurumi's solution (assuming bash and POSIX shell is probably better)
because then it doesn't matter where in the line that space value occurs.

BUT why don't you concatenate the two values and have just 1 sql query?

$ab=`...  select 10 + 11 from dual;`

You may have to consult with you oracle friends to get this exactly right, but in the SQL Sybase DB (and probably MS SQL), this wouldn't be a problem.

ALSO, Stop using backquotes, they are deprecated since 1992 (at least)
ab=$( cmd ) is so much nicer ;-)

Edit: fixed the "sidedness" of `${x% }` (right) and `${x# }` (left). 2023-10-16

IHTH

Comment: hi shelter thanks for your response.here i must need seperate query instead of dual am going to fetch the value from some other table. i gave echo ${a% }${b% } like this... its again giving 10 11.plz help me out?

Comment: @jcrshankar : please refresh my reply, I have added several other comments that may help you. Also, use echo X${a% }Y${b% }Z to see where all the spaces are.

Comment: i used a=$( cmd ) b=$( cmd ).... as per your suggestion. and i gave echo ${a% }${b% } still its giving 10 11?

Comment: @jcrshankar : what does echo X${a}Y${b}Z show? Aso try kurumi's alternate ${a/ //}. Sorry just saw your comment about ${a// }. So now tell us which shell you are using? Ksh, bash, dash, zsh, ?? The error # looks like AIX Unix?

Comment: X 10Y 11Z its giving like this

Comment: So the space is on the front of the variable, not the back. use `echo ${a# }${b# }`  Good luck!

Comment: yup, but after giving echo ${a# }${b# } also the result is 10 11

Comment: Is it possible there are more than 1 space at the front? of ${b}. That is the only thing I can see, OR is the other stuff you are doing that you're not telling us about? OR add another 2 lines a=$(echo ${a}) ; b=$(echo ${b})

Comment: a1=$(echo ${a#}) ; 
b1=$(echo ${b#}) ;
echo $a1$b1;  ITS GIVING WHAT I NEED... THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
c="$a$b"
echo ${c// }
```

or remove spaces at each individual variables themselves

```
a=${a// } 
b=${b// }
```

or you can call externals

```
echo $a | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//'
```

Comment: a=${a// }: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command. am getting this error? for both the case plz help me?

Comment: no kurumi... i used c=$a$b
echo $c | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' ... to remove leading and trailling space.. stil its giving 10 11.

Comment: That's because my example changes variable `$a` not `$c`. The sed command is used to trim trailing and leading spaces. If you combine a and b to c, then `echo  $c | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'`

Comment: kurmi ,a=$(sqlplus -s ${usrid} <<EOF
set pause    off
set heading  off
set feedback off
set serveroutput off;
select 10 from dual;
exit;
EOF) its giving 10 plus \t and \n i think, so in sed we need remove both space and newline is it correct?

Comment: ok, if you are using GNU sed, you might be able to do `sed -r 's/[[:space:]]//'`